# How can we install FFMPEG for Ruby app on heroku?

Tags: ruby, git, heroku, ffmpeg, sinatra

I am trying to install FFMPEG for a Ruby app(Web framework- Sinatra) on Heroku. I have tried heroku-buildpack-multi (github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git) plugin, but seems it's stopped working from Jan 01,2017 as it threw error with same message. I followed steps from this link https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg

There is not much information regarding FFMPEG installation on Heroku. Can any one suggest some solution?

[Attaching error from heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCxCX.png)

Comment: What error message? Please add more information to your question

Comment: I have attached error message in the question itself. Please review.

Comment: That's not an error, but a warning. Just follow the instructions in the message and you're ok

Comment: @lifeisfoo Thanks for your reply. Warning says 'This buildpack will cease to function at the stroke of midnight on January 1, 2017'. After that Heroku threw error -  'Push got rejected, Failed to compile Multipack app'. Is there any alternative to this or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you have followed instructions in the warning message?

Answer (score 0):

I am finally able to install FFMPEG for ruby app on Heroku using different buildpacks. In case someone faces similar issue, just add following buildpacks using Heroku CLI
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/ruby
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/kontentcore/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg

Comment: Did you also install libx264?